# using google map geocoding service at service side

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

i wrote the following code to get the coordinate of a address

```
package test;
```

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import sun.net.www.content.text.PlainTextInputStream;

public class a{

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception{
     String address = "台北市信義路五段七號101樓";

     // 查詢經緯度
     String output = "csv";
     String key = "";
     String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=台北市信義路五段七號101樓&output=csv&key=ABQIAAAAXDq__hWKi9eMCwnn7LrMCxT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxSnSVp_Xlsd4Ph5iyMua7PE5E0x_A";

     URL iurl = new URL(url);
     HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)iurl.openConnection();
     uc.connect();
     Object content = uc.getContent();
    // 讀取結果
    PlainTextInputStream sr = (PlainTextInputStream)content;
    byte[] buf = new byte[2000];
    // 解析 200,8,25.033408,121.564099  (HTTP status code, accuracy, latitude, longitude)
    sr.read(buf);

    String[] tmpArray = new String(buf, "UTF-8").split(",");
    String latitude = tmpArray[2];
    String longitude = tmpArray[3];

}
```

}

The problem is that the content i got a 400 code in result
i put the url in the browser, it return a 200 instead.

Is there a way to do that in a none browser matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have u tried Google Geo Kit
http://gglgeo.codeplex.com/? it is also in Java.